# Path to local maven repository programmatically?

Tags: java, matlab, maven

I want to determine location of local maven repository inside Matlab and do this in the same way `mvn` command does. Is this possible?

Also, I don't want to resemble entire Maven logic explicitly.

Are there any jars I can import and know where Maven expects local repository located?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading artifacts from remote maven repo programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781791/downloading-artifacts-from-remote-maven-repo-programmatically)

Comment: As a note: The "entire Maven logic" is actually pretty simple. Maven looks for the `settings.xml` in subdirectory `.m2` in the user directory. If it does not exist or contains no entry regarding the local repository, the local repository is just `.m2/repository`. Otherwise, read the new local repository from the `settings.xml`.

Comment: @JFMeier how to prove this (for ex by documentation)?

Comment: This is just by experience. Alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916157/how-to-get-the-maven-local-repo-location may help.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the repository is defined by the `localRepository` entry of the configuration file called `setting.xml`, which is located in `{M2_HOME}\conf\` and looks like this:

```
<settings>
    <!-- ... -->
    <localRepository>...</localRepository>
    <!-- ... -->
</settings>
```

If the configuration file doesn't exist or doesn't contain the aforementioned entry, the default location is used, which corresponds to:

- `~/.m2/repository` under `*NIX / MaxOS`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\{USERNAME}\.m2\repository` under `Windows`

The only solution for you is to locate the `setting.xml` file and parse it in order to extract the location of the repository. If the latter is not defined, you have to defaultize it properly depending on the current underlying operating system.

This process could be tricky, especially if you have to implement cross-system compatibility in your Matlab code. I suggest you an alternative which involves the [system function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html):

```
[status,cmdout] = system('mvn help:effective-settings');
```

If the command runs without issues, the `cmdout` will contain the whole content of the `setting.xml` file. Once you have it, you can parse the XML data and find the folder.

Comment: The solution is not complete as Maven may be running with the -s options specifying a different location of the settings file. This can be done either explicitly or by adding the flag ot .mvn/maven.config (in versions of Maven after 3.3.x). Also, the repository may have been specirfied using the maven.repo.local Java system property.